# Setting default color without messing up page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

So I have a script that converts RGB to HEX, and vise versa. But when I load the page the background is black. So I went to the corresponding part in my code, which is below.

```
function update() {
    var red = parseInt($(".r").val(), 10);
    var green = parseInt($(".g").val());
    var blue = parseInt($(".b").val());
    red = red || 255;
    green = green || 255;
    blue = blue || 255;
    var rgb = RGB2HTML(red, green, blue);
    $(".hex").val(rgb);
   $("body").css("background", rgb);
}
```

And I changed

```
red = red || 0;
green = green || 0;
blue = blue || 0;
```

To

```
red = red || 255;
green = green || 255;
blue = blue || 255;
```

So now when I do `0, 157, 255` I get this [image]

So I go back to the default `0`. And when I enter the same RGB I get this

[image]

So my first question is, how can I choose my own background for initial launch without messing up the whole script. My second question is when I enter a HEX with the `#` prefix. The script wont run. This is what I expect. But when I do RGB to HEX, it puts a `#` in the HEX field. So I want to prevent that from happening. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/lusukodo/7) a demo for the black background. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your JavaScript, you have:

```
$(function () {
    $('.r, .g, .b').keyup(update);
    update();
});
```

This is running `update();` which sets the background color. You can probably remove that line and add a color to the `body` in the CSS to your preferred color.

```
body {
  color:#f00;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Secondly, when you change an RGB value, the hex value is being updated with a # inside the input because you are explicitly setting that. In `update()` you call `RGB2HTML()` which performs and sets the hex input to:

```
return '#' + hex(red) + hex(green) + hex(blue);
```

Remove that, then you can add it in the last line of update() so the input doesn't get it but it is included when setting the background.

```
$("body").css("background", "#" + rgb);
```

http://jsbin.com/ziyicebo/2

In terms of your pink / blue issue, the reason it is not working is because you are setting different colors. When it reaches:

```
red = red || 255;
```

red becomes 255 not 0 as entered. In the other instance, r was still 0. A color with r=0 is different than r=255. You can do an isNaN check to check if the resulting integer is valid as opposed to how you are doing it now.

Comment: This solves nearly all the problem. But the issue with incorrect result.

Comment: Where the # gets added to the hex field? Yes, that was the second half. Please clarify.

Comment: Well the sending part to the first question. See the pink and blue screensots above? I enter the same RGB, but get different HEX.

Comment: I've added to my answer. It is a different color because your code is setting a different color when the value you entered is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to do this instead to fix the first issue:

```
red = isNaN(red) ? 255 : red;
green = isNaN(green) ? 255 : green;
blue = isNaN(blue) ? 255 : blue;
```

For the second issue change RGB2HTML to not return '#':

```
function RGB2HTML(red, green, blue) {
    return hex(red) + hex(green) + hex(blue);
}
```

and then change `$("body").css("background", rgb);` to prepend '#':

```
$("body").css("background", '#' + rgb);
```